# Uncaught reference error: jQuery is not defined (Sticky div)

Tags: jquery

Plz Help fix It

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var stickyOffset = jQuery("canbesticky").offset().top;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollPos >= stickyOffset) {
            jQuery("canbesticky").addClass("fixeddiv");
        } else {
            jQuery("canbesticky").removeClass("fixeddiv");
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle.net/daniladyabin/mnh4vn2y
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeX8Y.png)
    I'm new in JQuery

Comment: You didn't include jQuery

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/daniladyabin/mnh4vn2y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to actually include jQuery. On JsFiddle, there is an option in the JavaScript section to add it. In an actual webpage you will need to add a link to either a local version, or hosted version of the library.

You can use this to reference it online

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Next, all of your jQuery selectors are incorrect. To select an element by id, you need to add a `#` at the beginning, like this

```
var stickyOffset = jQuery("#canbesticky").offset().top;
```

Lastly, you can use a nice little shorthand to save yourself some typing. `jQuery` can be replaced with `$`, like this

```
var stickyOffset = $("#canbesticky").offset().top;
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery error has little to do with your error. In JSFiddle include

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
```

on the right, you can see that in the fiddle i will include, now you have jQuery in your fiddle. If you didn't do that in your actual code, include it there too as you **naturally need jQuery to use jQuery**. (Make sure it's https as JSFiddle doesn't accept http)

You are using `jQuery("canbesticky")` which would search for a tag `canbesticky` but you need to find a tag with the `id` `canbesticky`, so you have to adjust your CSS selector in `jQuery("//CSS Selector//")`.

That's as that: `jQuery("#canbesticky")`!

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/mnh4vn2y/1/).